# how to format simultaneously a string and floating number in awk?

Tags: shell, awk, format

I have a column as follows:

```
ifile.txt
1.25
2.78
?
?
5.6
3.4
```

I would like to format the floating points to decimal and skipping the strings as it is.

```
ofile.txt
1
3
?
?
6
3
```

Walter A, F. Knorr and Janez Kuhar suggested nice scripts to do it as per my question and need of a command like

```
awk '{printf "%d%s\n", $1}' ifile.txt
```

Again, I found I have a number of columns, however, other columns don't need any formatting. So I have to use the above command in the form of something like:

```
awk '{printf "%5s %d%s %5s %5s %5s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' ifile.txt
```

for example:

```
ifile.txt
1  1.25   23.2    34  3.4
2  2.78   22.0    23  1.2
3     ?      ?     ?  4.3
4     ?      ?     ?  6.5
5   5.6   45.0     5  2.4
6   3.4   43.0    23  5.6
```

I used the following command as again suggested by F. Knorr in answer,

```
awk '$2~/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/{$2=int($2+0.5)}1' ifile.txt > ofile.txt

ofile.txt
1  1 23.2    34  3.4
2  3 22.0    23  1.2
3  ?      ?     ?  4.3
4  ?      ?     ?  6.5
5  6 45.0     5  2.4
6  3 43.0    23  5.6
```

It works fine, but need to format it. like

```
ofile.txt
1  1   23.2    34  3.4
2  3   22.0    23  1.2
3  ?      ?     ?  4.3
4  ?      ?     ?  6.5
5  6   45.0     5  2.4
6  3   43.0    23  5.6
```

Comment: Can you have negative numbers in your file? If so include a couple of them in your example so we can see how you want them rounded up/down. Also include some .5 values so we can see if you want biased (round up) or unbiased (round to even) rounding or something else! Finally - you say in your comments your real input has multiple columns so show sample input with multiple columns so you and we don't waste time reworking potential solutions. Always make your sample as close to your real data as possible while keeping it concise enough for us to read quickly/easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first check whether the column contains a number (via regex) and then handle the printing accordingly:

```
 awk '$1~/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/{printf "%i\n",$1+0.5; next}1' test.txt
```

**Update:** If it is the n-th column that needs to be formatted as described above (and no other formatting in other columns), then replace all `$1` by `$n` in the following command:

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/{$1=int($1+0.5)}1' test.txt
```

Comment: This seems great. Could you please suggest me how can I used this command if I have a number of columns, however, no other columns don't need any formatting?

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the answer. However I have still problem with the required format (I have updated my question). I tried a lot to make as per my format, but no success. Would you mind to help?

Comment: The problem is that your columns are separated by a varying number of blanks. By default, awk treats any sequence of blanks as a column-separator. An easy solution would by something like `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}$2~/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/{$2=int($2+0.5)}1' test
` which yields a file in which columns are separated by a single blank. If you want to preserve the original format, i would have to think a little more...

Comment: Thank you so much @F. Knorr. Your suggestion and help solved my problem now. I used your command with a tab:  `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$2~/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/{$2=int($2+0.5)}1'`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a half can be done with:

```
awk ' $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$/ { printf("%d\n", $1 + 0.5); next }
      { print $1 } ' file
```

or slightly shorter:

```
awk ' $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$/ { printf("%d\n", $1 + 0.5); next } 1' file
```

Comment: It is working fine for one column. I have many other columns, but they don't need formats. Could you please suggest how to use this?

Comment: `awk ' $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$/ { printf("%d\n", $1 + 0.5); shift; print $0; next } 1' file`

Comment: That will convert a string like '4x2' to the number `4` due to the unescaped `.`. It also won't work for negative numbers but idk if those can exist in the OPs files.

Comment: @EdMorton is right, see the corrections in the answer and discussion of @F.Knorr (backslash before the dot, do you have negative numbers (where you should substract, not add, a half), what do you want with `7.`.